# Problema con importaciones en Python

Tags: python, rutas

Tengo dos paquetes de Python, cada uno con un archivo dentro. Estos paquetes, están en la raíz, por lo que son carpetas vecinas.
Ambos paquetes llevan su **init**.py.

La importación está funcionando, porque la utilizo desde terceros módulos, sin embargo, cuando ejecuto desde el propio archivo donde quiero hacer el import, me da error de no module named 'nombre_modulo'.

```
> directorio proyecto
>     directorio1
>         -__init__.py
>         -archivo1.py
>     directorio2
>         -__init__.py
>         -archivo2.py
```

quiero importar el archivo 1 en el 2.

Lo he probado de todas las maneras que se me ocurren. Una de ellas:

```
from directorio1 import archivo1
```

Comment: Un ejemplo con peras y manzanas ayudaría: Tengo dos directorios /dir1, /dir2 con tales contenidos. Tengo un directorio ??? con un archivo que hace un "import xxx" ...

Comment: Ya está, a ver si eso ilustra más.

Comment: He probado lo mismo desde Pycharm, con los mismos intérpretes y no falla como en Visual Studio Code. ¿Alguien sabe que puede ser? ¿Podría ser una extensión? ¿bug de VSCode?

Comment: Las rutas de ambos archivos no son visibles entre sí. Una forma de importarlos sería `from ..directorio1 import archivo1`. O si en el directorio padre, hay un paquete (supongamos que se llama "padre") que exponga a directorio1 entonces podrias hacer algo como `from padre.directorio1 import archivo1`. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

por lo general cada carpeta es un modulo, entonces solo te deja ver los archivos que estén dentro del modulo.

con el siguiente código podrás subir un nivel y ver los modulos que estén al mismo nivel que el tuyo

```
### Con esto importo el proyecto para jalar cosas de los demas modulos
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, f'{os.getcwd()}')

from directorio1 import archivo1
```